# Listing categories in Google Sheet

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have this Google sheet:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1vMgNAAQmx2Yv9xCTAoLF9His9nagWlD69jGEuKAF2b4/edit?usp=sharing

I have several categories, I need to automate in front of each row which categories have #1 filled like the example.

If the category does not have "1" it will not appear, if the "1" is there, then the row should have the name of the category.

I have tried several things like this:
https://infoinspired.com/google-docs/spreadsheet/search-across-columns-and-return-the-header/

Do you have any idea of a better approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In row 2 try

```
=ArrayFormula(trim(split(transpose(query(transpose(if(A2:E=1, A1:E1&"/",)),,5000)),"/")))
```

and see if that works?

[image]